# stop propagation after body mouseup event with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouseup

Have two events:

```
 $('body').mouseup(function(e){}
```

and

```
$('.toggle').click(function(e){}
```

I only want one of these to trigger. I tried

```
 e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); return false;
```

but that doesn't seem to stop it. Any ideas? the mouseup is triggered first.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have `$('body').mousedown(function(e){}`?. `e.stopPropagation();` stops bubbling events and `e.preventDefault();` prevents the default behavior of elements such as submitting a form or clicking a link. What do you want to stop?

Comment: I need to close a drawer that slides out from the side of the page, closing is done when the user clicks anywhere on the page.

Comment: And where did you try `e.stopPropagation();`?

Comment: In both of the event functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is they are two different events.  If you want to prevent the body.onmouseup, you need to add something on .toggle to catch/stop mouseup events; like

```
$('.toggle').mouseup(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    // these two are older ways I like to add to maximize browser compat
    e.returnValue = false;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    return false; 
}
```